# how long does it take to family share request to come?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

How long does it take to family share request to come ?I have shared it like a day ago and it doesn't come to me please help

Comment: I think we'll need more details on what exactly happened.

Answer (score 1):

Family share requests are almost instant, assuming everything works properly. For me, they have always taken less time than logging out and into the other Steam account.

There's clearly an issue here that isn't needing to wait but without a lot more information, we won't be able to help.